# improving views performace in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, view, pivot, transpose

I have one view vwBalance which returns more than 150.000.000 rows, bellow is the code:

```
SELECT    *
FROM            dbo.balance INNER JOIN
                         dbo.NomBalance   ON dbo.balance.IdNomBil = dbo.NomBalance.Id
```

But I want to transpose the values return so I use a PIVOTE function like this:

```
SELECT  An, cui,caen, col1, col2, ... col 100
FROM   (SELECT     cui, valoare, cod_campbil,caen,An
        FROM vwBilant  WITH (NOLOCK)
        p PIVOT (MAX(valoare) FOR cod_campbil IN ( col1, col2, ... col100   ) AS pvt
```

The questions are:

1. Should i use query hint inside the view vwBalance? This hint could improve or could lock the transpose action?
2. It's a problem if I use NOLOCK hint instead of the other query hints?
3. There are better ways to improve transposing many columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Transposing 150.000.000 rows wow. Have you looked into [`Column Store Indexes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg492153.aspx), You have the typical scenario where this new feature in Sql Server 2012 can come real handy.

Comment: Do you really need to pivot this data in a query runtime? How often did your data can change? Do you really need always fresh data? Did you think about loading this data into another table in transformed form?

Answer (score 1):

I can give the following adviсes:

1. you can use hint `readpast` if it does not broke your business logic
2. you can create clustered index for this view. It materialize you view, but performance of changing operation will be decreased for all tables that are used in this view.
3. also, you should check indexes for fields that you use in join and where clauses.
4. and you can use preprocessing. So, you insert this values in some
       another table (for example at night). In this case you can use
       [columnstore index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg492153%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) or just make page compression for this table
       as well as you can use page [compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc280449.aspx) for all tables that are
       used in this view.